# Best practices for configuring SORM

Tags: scala, sorm

I wonder if anyone can share some best practices for using SORM, with reference to using in actor systems and with automated testing (unit/functional).

How do you:

- drive your DB/Instance singleton from externalized configuration that's constructed at runtime (eg. typesafe's application.conf)
- do dependency injection (either constructor or cake pattern or ?) to use the same code with production/test DBs .. or do you use another strategy altogether?

It seems that when I don't declare my "Instance" as a singleton (object extends Instance) but rather create a new Instance for injecting into my actors for testing, I encounter strange stack traces using SORM. I used scala 2.10.2/3, SORM 0.38/9 with the same results. Here's my (only) entity:

```
object TapJoy {
  private val SECRET_KEY = "aaa"

  case class AddCreditsRequest(tapJoyId: String, verifier: String, currency: Int, snuid: Long) {
    val created = new DateTime()
   <some methods omitted>
  }
}
```

stack traces:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef$$anon$3 cannot be cast to scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readSymbolRef(UnPickler.scala:788)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readType(UnPickler.scala:355)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$LazyTypeRef$$anonfun$34.apply(UnPickler.scala:855)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$LazyTypeRef$$anonfun$34.apply(UnPickler.scala:855)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.at(UnPickler.scala:171)
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$LazyTypeRef.complete(UnPickler.scala:855)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1229)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.thisInfo(Types.scala:2399)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.baseClasses(Types.scala:2404)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.findMembers(Types.scala:1093)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.membersBasedOnFlags(Types.scala:718)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.members(Types.scala:661)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.members(Types.scala:343)
at sorm.reflection.ScalaApi$TypeApi.members(ScalaApi.scala:11)
at sorm.reflection.ScalaApi$TypeApi.properties(ScalaApi.scala:13)
at sorm.reflection.Reflection.properties(Reflection.scala:31)
at sorm.core.Initialization$.errors(Initialization.scala:29)
at sorm.Instance$Initialization$$anonfun$2.apply(Instance.scala:212)
at sorm.Instance$Initialization$$anonfun$2.apply(Instance.scala:212)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:74)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
at sorm.Instance$Initialization.<init>(Instance.scala:212)
at sorm.Instance.<init>(Instance.scala:29)
```

or

```
scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$CyclicReference: illegal cyclic reference involving method productPrefix
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol$$anonfun$info$3.apply(Symbols.scala:1218)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol$$anonfun$info$3.apply(Symbols.scala:1216)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.lock(Symbols.scala:482)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1216)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.tpe(Symbols.scala:1200)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.tpeHK(Symbols.scala:1201)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.computeMemberType(Types.scala:784)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$MethodSymbol.typeAsMemberOf(Symbols.scala:2646)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.memberType(Types.scala:779)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.findMembers(Types.scala:1117)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.membersBasedOnFlags(Types.scala:718)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.members(Types.scala:661)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.members(Types.scala:343)
at sorm.reflection.ScalaApi$TypeApi.members(ScalaApi.scala:11)
at sorm.reflection.ScalaApi$TypeApi.properties(ScalaApi.scala:13)
at sorm.reflection.Reflection.properties(Reflection.scala:31)
at sorm.core.Initialization$.errors(Initialization.scala:29)
at sorm.Instance$Initialization$$anonfun$2.apply(Instance.scala:212)
at sorm.Instance$Initialization$$anonfun$2.apply(Instance.scala:212)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:74)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
at sorm.Instance$Initialization.<init>(Instance.scala:212)
at sorm.Instance.<init>(Instance.scala:29)
```

Comment: There's absolutely no obligation to make SORM's instance a singleton. Seems like the issue is in your code. Please provide a more informative example, which at least includes the declaration of the instance.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to come up with a contrived example. Any input on my other questions would be appreciated .. and would make a nice addition to the docs?

Answer (score 2):

> How do you drive your DB/Instance singleton from externalized configuration that's constructed at runtime (eg. typesafe's application.conf)?

Pretty straight-forward. E.g.:

```
val db = {
  val config = readAndParseConfigDataSomehow()
  new sorm.Instance( 
    entities = ...,
    url = config.url,
    user = config.url,
    password = config.url,
    poolSize = config.poolSize,
    initMode = config.initMode
  )
}
```

> How do you do dependency injection (either constructor or cake pattern or ?) to use the same code with production/test DBs .. or do you use another strategy altogether?

There really aren't any special requirements imposed by SORM. You can pass the instance over however fits you, like any other value, so the actual instance utilized can be context-dependent: a function or a constructor parameter, e.g. `def doSomeStuffWithDB( db : sorm.Instance ){ ... }`, even implicit parameters if you're a fan of them (I know I'm not). The choice of the strategies is really up to you.

Concerning switching between the production and test environments - you've already presented one evident solution - config files.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I put together a simple (but hopefully not contrived) sample app using Spray, Akka & SORM. It currently show the problems from my first post: https://github.com/nefilim/sas I'd be curious to know if you can replicate them, just running the tests with sbt.

Comment: ps. Be warned, I'm pretty new to Scala ;)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to analyze the project. At a first glance it looks immensely overcomplicated with all kinds of patterns without any real purpose. I can however give you an advice on solving the issue: first get rid of redundant layers [like this](https://github.com/nefilim/sas/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/nefilim/sas/persistence/SormEntities.scala), then isolate the problem by incrementally simplifying the code down to a simple solution presented in my answer.

Comment: i can reliably get both linked projects tests to complete successfully if i make these two adjustments:   1. set scalaVersion to 2.10.3 and  2. parallelExecution in Test := false   reading through the above scala issue isn't very encouraging: reflection API is experimental, runtime reflection should be serialized etc

Comment: Thanks for your research. I was able to reproduce runtime errors with Scala 2.10.1 and 2.10.2, I suspect the issue appears when multiple instances get constructed concurrently. Anyway, simply changing the Scala version to 2.10.3 (without setting `Test := false`) makes the test pass successfully on my end.

Comment: it's only passing because there's only one test, i've committed another, it should fail for you now without **parallelExecution in Test := false** in build.sbt   - as it stands, it would appear that SORM isn't production ready? is there a way to synchronize the reflection blocks in SORM until scala is fixed?

Comment: You've confirmed yourself that this is a bug of SORM only by succession from a bug of Scala. So the proper question then should be: is Scala production-ready? But the thing is, this is more of a marketing term and it has absolutely nothing to say about the presence of bugs in a product. All evolving projects inevitably have them from time to time. I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/27), let's move our discussion there, because it's starting to violate SO rules. You'll see my reply to your suggestion to use synchronization there.

Comment: It looks like synchronization of Instance creation solve the problem:

   lazy val connection = {
     TestDatabaseCreationLock.synchronized {
       new TestDB
     }
   }



object TestDatabaseCreationLock


class TestDB extends Instance(
...
)